Int and Long paramters show as "not set" in firebase analytics console
I have an event with three parameters, a String a Long, and another one is Int.
The event triggered successfully and the value of the String parameter is showing in Firebase Analytics Console, but Int and Long parameters show as "not set" and no value is reported for them!
I have checked the Custom Definitions section in Firebase Console and the parameter's names are there.
In Debug View all parameters that I want are set and they have their values but nothing is showing in Console!
Has anybody any solution for solving this?
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("product_name", "test")
bundle.putInt("product_quantity", 2)
bundle.putLong("product_amount", 1000L)
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).logEvent("MyEvent", bundle)

I expect all parameters with any type that I put in bundle, show correctly in Firebase Analytics Console
